# Flutter dynamic list foreach

Tags: flutter, list, dynamic

I Have a list and items [0,1,2,3,4,5]

when i try to print this list

i get output like this:  `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

But I want to get output like this

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

My Code:

```
GFButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _mainController.selected_Tags
                  .forEach((element) => print(element));
            },
            text: "Test",
          )
```

Comment: How to reproduce the issue? I did a similar thing and got the second output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved issue;

```
<pre>
_mainController.selected_Tags.forEach((innerList) {
      innerList.forEach((element) {
        print(element);
      });
    });
</pre>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

*I'm assuming you mean the other way around in your question (**without** line breaks). As your code *does* print in multiple lines.*

Try:

```dart
void main() {
  final List<int> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  print(numbers.join('')); // --> 12345
}
```

it will join the `numbers` without anything as the delimiter. You can also join with a comma if you want:

```
numbers.join(', ')
```

Comment: When i try this output is same.
`I/flutter ( 5683): [1, 2]`
I want to print the values returned from the array one under the other. but I can print one line at a time.